# How to extract all the values in a Smartsheet

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to extract data column-wise from a Smartsheet. I used the below code, but I'm getting row-wise values instead. How can I get it in column-wise format?

```
MySheet = ss_client.Sheets.get_sheet(Sheet_ID)
for MyRow in MySheet.rows:
    for MyCell in MyRow.cells:
        print(MyRow.id, MyCell.value)
    print('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what Software2 was saying, your code would look something like this:

```
sheet_ID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
col_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

MySheet = ss_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_ID)

for MyRow in MySheet.rows:
    for MyCell in MyRow.cells:
        if MyCell.column_id == col_id:
            if (MyCell.value):
                print (MyRow.id, MyCell.value, MyCell.column_id)
    print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Each cell in a row will have a corresponding `columnId` that matches one of the column IDs in the sheet. You will need to [retrieve the column id](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-column) of the column you're looking for, then check against that id.

See the [API documentation](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-row) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example about how to print a Smartsheet sheet as Pandas DataFrame.

Installation

Requirements

pip install smartsheet-dataframe

pip install pandas

```
from smartsheet_dataframe import get_as_df, get_sheet_as_df

sheet_id = "" #Copy the sheet id from the Smartsheet website and paste between "".
token_code = "" #Generate token code from the Smartsheet website and paste between "".
df = get_as_df(type_='sheet',
           token=token_code,
           id_=sheet_id)
print(df)
```

Source: https://libraries.io/pypi/smartsheet-dataframe